# How to customize the soap <FaultCode>

Tags: jakarta-ee, apache-camel

```
<soap:Fault>
     <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
```

I want to customize the soap:Server String with my custom String.

I am using camel cxf for my project. and using POJO model to consume and expose the service.

Answer (score 0):

`faultCode` takes a `QName` as value, i.e. it needs a name defined in a certain namespace. In your example, check for the namespace definition for the short code `soap`, it will probably be `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` since you haven't customized anything.

To change it, you will have to manually construct a fault object in your code, and set a `QName` in the `faultCode` field, something like this (Assuming SOAP 1.1, 1.2 will be similar)

```
SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();
SOAPFault fault = body.addFault();
QName faultName = new QName("http://your.namespace.here.com/and/some/more", "Your Error code here");
fault.setFaultCode(faultName);
fault.setFaultActor("Fault actor name");
fault.setFaultString("Say what's wrong here");
```

[You can read more about it here.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnbin/index.html)